# Rails Code Input/Form Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is anybody aware of any resources/gems for code fields in a rails form? I am looking for the ability to have a form field where a user can submit formatted code -- so that a user can edit small snippets of code in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror is a great solution for this.  I have no experience with the gem, but I've dropped in CodeMirror manually before and it's super simple and produces a great UI for editing code.

Direct link: http://codemirror.net/

Gem: https://github.com/fixlr/codemirror-rails